# Copy entire database from CD ISO to Ubuntu (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I have ubuntu 11.10 (target system) with PostgreSQL running on it.
Also I have CD image of another Linux OS with PostgreSQL in it with some existing database.
What I want is to copy the database from OS CD with postgreSQL to the target system (ubuntu).
How is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a virtual machine (for example using qemu-kvm), restore OS from this CD to virtual machine and use `pg_dumpall` in it to backup a database. Then restore it to new computer.

If it is't that easy, for example because your backup on CD is not of a full system, you can use for example virtual machine with a LiveCD which has the same major version of Postgres. You could copy data directory from backup CD (in my RPM based distributions it is in /var/lib/pgsql) to virtual machine and then use `pg_dumpall`.

But sometimes it is much more economic to give this job to somebody which is fluent in Linux and Postgres administration - it would cost you for example $60 but it will be done in an hour.